# Min Heap using STL Priority Queue explanation

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I am fairly new to C++ and I was trying to implement a Min Heap using Priority Queue STL in C++. I looked around the web and chanced upon a code, the link to which I have added at the bottom.

I understand how vectors work and I also understand what a functor is but I can't understand how 'return i>j' plays a part in arranging the elements from minimum to maximum.

I will post the code here.

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct comparator {
     bool operator()(int i, int j) {
     return i > j;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, comparator> minHeap;

    minHeap.push(10);
    minHeap.push(5);
    minHeap.push(12);
    minHeap.push(3);
    minHeap.push(3);
    minHeap.push(4);

    while (!minHeap.empty()) {
    cout << minHeap.top() << " ";
    minHeap.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please trace the program's execution? I have been trying to understand how this program works for the past couple of hours with no luck.

I got the code from [here](https://codeconnect.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/max-min-heap-using-c-stl/)

Comment: Do you have a debugger you can use to trace the execution?

Comment: If you'd like to trace the program's execution, every compiler also has a related debugger, a tool that you, yourself, can use to step through the code, and see how it works, step by step. You will do yourself a big favor if you invest some time in learning how to use your debugger to step through the code you have compiled. A skill that, sadly, many posters to stackoverflow.com sorely lack.

Comment: I am a newbie to programming and have not learnt how to use a debugger yet. But I will learn it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority queues first element is always the greatest of the elements it contains, according to a given criterion. This criterion is your functor `comparator`. In this case, it's defining that for a two given elements the minor one should be first.

Hence, in your code, if we extract all the elements the output will be the element ordered min to max:

```
while (!minHeap.empty()) {
   cout << minHeap.top() << " ";
   minHeap.pop();
}
//output: 3,3,4,5,10,12
```

The algorithm to push an element is like a heap:

1. Place the new element in the next available position in the array. (lower level of the tree)
2. Compare the new element with its parent using the functor provided (`comparator`).  In this case, you comparison is "if the 
   new element is smaller", then swap it with its parent.
3. Continue this process until either:

   - the new element’s parent is smaller than or 
     equal to the new element, or
   - the new element reaches the root (index 0 of 
     the array)

Maybe it is more clear to see how the algorithm works with a visual example: Imagine you have already pushed the numbers 6,3,5,9 and now you push 2.
[image]

Comment: When I push 10, could you please tell me what the values of I and j would be?

Comment: Also could you tell me in which part of the code the parent of the current element is found/extracted for comparison?

Comment: As it is the first element no comparison will be made. You can check the trace of the functor by adding inside the function the line:
`std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl`

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you also answer the other question?

Comment: When the function push is executed  the comparison with the parent (step 2) is executed in a recursive like manner (step 3). To find the parent of a giving node there are various possibilities depending on how the structure is represented, the most common ones are: if represented with arrays have a math function that returns the parent idx or; if represented as a tree having a pointer to it.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I'll try to wrap my head around it.